# Why can't user with SQLAgentOperatorRole delete his own SQL jobs

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, role, jobs, sql-server-agent

I created a login and a user. I assigned the user as the db owner of the database "test". Then I granted him the role `SQLAgentOperatorRole` so that he can delete/create/modify the jobs belonging to the database "test". But I can only view the jobs though I have granted `SQLAgentOperatorRole`. What should I do to allow this user to do anything to the jobs belonging to the database "test" ? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not part of the definition of `SQLAgentOperatorRole` permissions.

The login being an owner of database "test" does not influence how SQL Agent jobs are managed. Being a `db_owner` of the database means that a job with that owner can take almost any action within the "test" database, but it says little about operating the SQL Agent job itself

The `SQLAgentOperatorRole` permissions are describe in the following link.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx

Look for the topic: **The following table summarizes SQLAgentOperatorRole permissions on SQL Server Agent objects.**

This clearly shows that the `SQLAgentOperatorRole` will allow the login to create/delete/modify SQL Agent jobs that are **owned by** the user's login.  However, the login can be used to issue commands to enable/disable other SQL Agent jobs and job schedules.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SQL Server documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx), a user with a `SQLAgentOperatorRole` can only modify jobs that it created itself.